# Combining two .csv files into one with Pandas in Jupyter Notebook/Python

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have two separate .csv files that look entirely different, i.e.
`.csv1= Author name, date csv was created, details about the data basically,
and .csv2=actual data.'

Both of them are generated externally from Jupyter and while I could easily do it manually, I'm interested if there's a way to combine them into one csv that would have csv1 at the top, and then below it would have the data in csv2 as to save time.

I've tried merge, and append, but they seem to work with dataframes and not csv's and because the two csv's are so different, I think it's another method but I'm unsure what it is, as it stands the only code I have is reading in the two csv files.

Comment: You'd read the CSV in as dataframes and merge using Pandas and then use Pandas to save dataframe in CSV. You need to provide more details such as a toy data that reflects enough about each CSV file to get useful hints back. Read about a minimal reproducible example in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also likely this has nothing to do with Jupyter Notebook and 'Jupyter Notebook' should not be in the title. You can mention it in passing but you seem to be describing doing this in Python and or Pandas. Those work with Python separate from Jupyter, ...

Comment: <continued> such as when running Python code in a script that you kick off by running `python my_script.py` on the command line. Writing a dataframe back to CSV, see [pandas.DataFrame.to_cs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). You may want to see the `index=True` as it is commonly used because often you don't want the row line numbers in the output CSV. And I say you can mention you are using Jupyter and not a script because sometimes there are tricks that can be used or sometimes certain things need to be run in two cells. Shouldn't be the case here.

Comment: So you just want to append one CSV-file to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to combine two files `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` then `copyfileobj` from the standard library module `shutil` offers an efficient method for large files (with chunking):

```py
from shutil import copyfileobj

with open("combined.csv", "w") as fout:
    for file in "file1.csv", "file2.csv":
        with open(file, "r") as fin:
            copyfileobj(fin, fout)
```

If the file are not that large you could also do:

```py
with open("combined.csv", "w") as fout:
    for file in "file1.csv", "file2.csv":
        with open(file, "r") as fin:
            fout.write(fin.read())
```

In case the transition from the 1. to the 2. file gets messed up due to a missing newline character at the end of the last content line of the 1. file, you could replace the last line of the code with:

```py
...
            fout.write(fin.read().rstrip("\n") + "\n")
```

Now, if the files are too large *and* the transition gets messed up, you could do something like the following:

```py
from fileinput import input as finput

with open("combined.csv", "w") as fout,\
     finput(["file1.csv", "file2.csv"]) as fin:
         line = next(fin)
         fout.write(line)
         for next_line in fin:
            if fin.isfirstline() and not line.endswith("\n"):
                next_line = "\n" + next_line
            fout.write(next_line)
            line = next_line
```

The `input` function from the standard library module `fileinput` offers a convenient way to iterate over all lines of a sequence of files, with some control checks over where in the sequence the current position is.

Or you could use the `csv` module from the standard library:

```py
import csv

with open("combined.csv", "w") as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for file in "file1.csv", "file2.csv":
        with open(file, "r") as fin:
            writer.writerows(csv.reader(fin))
```